# Elasticache Redis auto-backup into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redis, amazon-elasticache

I would like to back up my Elasticache Redis cluster everyday. I can setup automatic backups on AWS, however I would like to know how I can set the backups (.rdb files) to be exported into S3 everyday when the backups are created.

Answer (score 0):

this is a little hacky, but you could do it with a combination of cron and aws-cli. You could even (bonus points) run cron from aws lambda, thus eliminating the need for an external server. You'll need to install aws-cli on your lambda code (see this: https://alestic.com/2016/11/aws-lambda-awscli/ ). I didnt try any of this, but it should be possible with some work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Amazon S3 console.
2. Choose the name of the Amazon S3 bucket that you want to copy the backup to.
3. Choose the Permissions tab.
4. Scroll down on the Permissions page, select Access control list (ACL), and then select Edit.

Add grantee Canonical Id: 540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353

5. Select the following options listed:

Objects: List, Write

Bucket ACL: Read, Write

5. Choose Save.

Note: GovCloud Regions use a different ID:

Canonical Id:
40fa568277ad703bd160f66ae4f83fc9dfdfd06c2f1b5060ca22442ac3ef8be6

that's it you are good to upload your snapshot to s3